# Array is undefined in VueJS Object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm extremely new when it comes to using VueJS and so I am working on a small App that should list out an Authenticated person's Github repositories.
I'm having trouble when it comes to being able to access or even traverse the Array in the Picture below. I keep getting an error of `undefined`if I try userRepos. Please see my code below.

I do apologize for the "Wall of Code". But I thought these javascript code snippets are the most pertinent to the issue.

This is the GitHub repo I am using as the boilerplate for this project. [GitHub-Electron-Vue-OAuth](https://github.com/chamerling/electron-oauth-github-vue)

[image]

```js
const getAxiosClient = (state) => {
  return axios.create({
    baseURL: state.server.url, // this is "https://api.github.com
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'token ' + state.session.access_token
    },
    responseType: 'json'
  })
}
// Mutation
[types.SET_USER_REPOS](state, repos) {
  state.session.repos = repos;
},
// State Object
const state = {
  server: {
    url: 'http://api.github.com'
  },
  session: {
    access_token: window.localStorage.getItem('access_token'),
    ready: false,
    authenticated: false,
    user: {}
  }
};
// Actions
export const getRepos = ({
  commit,
  state
}) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    getAxiosClient(state).get('/user/repos').then(response => {
      commit(types.SET_USER_REPOS, response.data)
      resolve(response.data)
    }, err => {
      console.log(err)
      reject(err)
    })
  })
}

export const userRepos = (state) => {
  console.log(state.session.repos)
  return state.session.repos;
}
```

```html
<template lang="jade">
  .home
    span Hello {{ username }}
    span {{ userRepos }}
    
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'home',
    computed: {
      username() {
        return this.$store.getters.username;
      },
      userRepos() {
        return this.$store.getters.userRepos;
      }
    },
    // TODO: Push this in router
    beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
      next(vm => {
        if (!vm.$store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
          vm.$router.push({
            name: 'login'
          });
        } else {
          next();
        }
      });
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Would you mind posting your state object? I'm only seeing actions and mutations. You might be committing a mutation from the `response.data`, but Vue can't detect property additions.

Comment: Yes. I'll edit my original code to include the state object

Comment: I was able to get this to not return undefined by using. getRepos() { return this.$store.getters.repos } in the Home.vue page. Then in the getter I setup my function as `export const getRepos = (state) => { const userRepos = Array.from(state.session.repos).forEach( repo => { return repo.full_name }) return userRepos }

Comment: I believe your issue stems from setting your `state.user` object directly from `response.data`. Vue can't detect property additions to objects. They have `Vue.set()` as a workaround. Try that in your mutation. Also, you should use Vue's dev tools chrome plugin... it'll help a lot.